# Restoring options

Tags: mysql

What excatly flushing means in MYSQL? Is it like truncate table?
   I need to extract few tables from a database on a server on linux
   and then I need to restore it to multiple database across multiple server.

I am thinking of taking dump of the particular database on the first server 
   and then restore particular tables from the database to the multiple server

Example- I have a server called 'SA' and I have a database on that server called 'DA'
   then I need to extract few tables lets say TA and TB from the DA and restore it into
   other databases which may have TA TB on the same database DA

What approach will be good?

Answer (score 0):

Flush is used in mysql to clear several forms of internal data which is being called by the mysql engine by default. It will not clear the Data from the database instead it operates on temporary data.

- It just clears the internal cache data.
- It reloads the data from  the   server if needed.
- and it causes an implicit commit just like when we
  use any DDL commands. But it is not like Truncate.

Better, use mysqldump to dump your database and then you can restore it on any platform or server easily.

Comment: so once I get the dump of required tables I need to restore it to database of another server which may already have TA TB tables. So do I need to truncate them first and restore?

Comment: TRUNCATING IS NOT REQUIRED...IF YOU WANT TO GET THE DATA RETAINED, JUST KEEP IT OR ELSE YOU CAN TRUNCATE IT.